# Fetch distinct values of two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables with names as "network" and "user", both have one common column named as userid what i want is to select userid values from "user" which are not in userid column of "network".
 Its a MYSQL table,

Comment: Can we see what you have tried already? You could use a `JOIN` or a `NOT IN` for this.

Comment: thanks halfer, but the query was only a small part of what i have written(i mean its a long script) though your suggestion and answers below solved it

Comment: Next time, please show your attempt. If it is very long, pare it down into the smallest possible case that does what you are trying. I've downvoted this, incidentally, to counteract the inexplicable upvote. This question is not a good fit for here - please read the _Help_ section when you get a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
select userid from user where userid NOT IN (select userid from network);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.userID
FROM   user a LEFT JOIN network b
          ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE  b.userid IS NULL
```